# List if-else not giving the expected result

Tags: python, list, sorting, if-statement

I have the following list of list:

```
[['3', 2], ['2370447', 282], ['5300058', 610], ['81615', 615], ['3294332', 624], ['3078798', 624], ['1804986', 643]]
```

Please note that in index 5 and 6, the second item is identical.  I am trying to turn this list ordered on the second item in each list into a ranking.

I used the following if-else to correct for time when values were the same:

```
for i in range(len(sortedCounts)):
   if i == 0:
          sortedCounts[i][1] = 0
   elif sortedCounts[i][1] == sortedCounts[i-1][1]:
          sortedCounts[i][1] = i-1
   else: 
          sortedCounts[i][1] = i
```

However, when I print the list, I am getting different rankings even when the numbers are the same:

```
[['3', 0], ['2370447', 1], ['5300058', 2], ['81615', 3], ['3294332', 4], ['3078798', 5], ['1804986', 6]]
```

Expected output is:

```
[['3', 0], ['2370447', 1], ['5300058', 2], ['81615', 3], ['3294332', 4], ['3078798', 4], ['1804986', 6]]
```

Appreciate any advice, or if there is a better way, please advise.

Comment: What’s the expected output?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry - updated

Comment: `sortedCounts[i][1] == sortedCounts[i-1][1]` is not doing what you want, because you overwrote the right side of that expression with `i` or `i-1` on the previous iteration of the loop.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I am trying a solution where I just move everything to a new list of lists but have a tough time with the indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rank, last_value = -1, -1
for i, e in enumerate(sortedCount):
    if last_value < e[1]:
        rank = i
    last_value = e[1]
    sortedCount[i][1] = rank
```

Comment: This almost worked.  I expected to get a 6 in the last list of lists, but this elegant solution gives me 5:  [['3', 0], ['2370447', 1], ['5300058', 2], ['81615', 3], ['3294332', 4], ['3078798', 4], ['1804986', 5]]

Comment: Sorry, i missed that point. I edited my answer, replaced `rank += 1` into `rank = i`. It may works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code you expected

```
sortedCounts=[['3', 2], ['2370447', 282], ['5300058', 610], ['81615', 615], ['3294332', 624], ['3078798', 624], ['1804986', 643]]
i=0
while i<len(sortedCounts):
    if(sortedCounts[i][1]==sortedCounts[i+1][1]):
        sortedCounts[i][1]=sortedCounts[i+1][1]=i
        i=i+1
    elif(i==len(sortedCounts)):
        sortedCounts[i][1]=i
    else:
        sortedCounts[i][1]=i
    i=i+1
```

Comment: I was working on something similar per my note above but by using another list.  Your code almost work,[['3', 0], ['2370447', 1], ['5300058', 2], ['81615', 3], ['3294332', 4], ['3078798', 4], ['1804986', **643**]] but the last item in the list is not changing:

Comment: I have some mistake because it should be i< len(sortedCounts). It recorrect that. Now try that code

Comment: This works as well, it's closer to the solution I was trying but was messing up the indexing - thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by index 1 using `sorted`:

```
input = [['3', 2],['2370447', 282],['5300058', 610],['81615', 615],['3294332', 624],['3078798', 624],['1804986', 643]]
output = []
for i, x in enumerate(sorted(input, key=itemgetter(1))):
    x[1] = i
    output.append(x)
```

Short and sweet.

`[['3', 0], ['2370447', 1], ['5300058', 2], ['81615', 3], ['3294332', 4], ['3078798', 5], ['1804986', 6]]`

Answer (score 0):

using inbuilt sort function can solve this issue easily

```
input_data = [['3', 2], ['2370447', 282], ['5300058', 610], ['81615', 615], ['3294332', 624], ['3078798', 624], ['1804986', 643]]

input_data.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
result = input_data.copy()
for i in range(len(result)):
    result[i][1] = i

print(result)

"""
output 
[['3', 0], ['81615', 1], ['1804986', 2], ['2370447', 3], ['3078798', 4], ['3294332', 5], ['5300058', 6]]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the main reason you are not getting same index for elements at 5 and 6 is because your code is not going into elif statement because on updating the list

```
with value 
    sortedCounts[i][1] = i-1
```

which changes the list.

So, instead of directly changing the list you can create a variable change it and append it to a new list.

```
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(sortedCounts)):
        if i == 0:
            variable = 0
        elif sortedCounts[i][1] == sortedCounts[i-1][1]:
            variable = i-1
        else: 
            variable = i
        newList.append([sortedCounts[i][0], variable])
```